# Pyspark write CSV always written as Integer Type

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe that have `IntegerType` and `StringType` it is confirmed when I `printSchema()` my dataframe but when i try

```
generated_df.write.csv('test_generated.csv', header=True)
```

It always print it all the data as integer, some of my value as `00001` will be written as `1`

Is there any thing I should do? or how am I suppose to do?